# Laravel Excel - Get Active Cell or Row

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-excel

That's a simple question.

I'm building a PHP Excel from scratch and is a very useful package.
I need to catch the active cell or row to know which cells to modify and customize, I checked all methods in the package and I didn't found something that helped me.
I'm inserting some data like this:

```
$sheet->appendRow(array(
                $variable->value1,
                $variable->value2,
                $variable->value3,
            ));
```

And then I want to customize some things(This example I'm changing the background color), something like:

```
//The XXX is the last active row that I append some value before
$sheet->cells('XXXX',function ($cells){
                $cells->setBackground('#34EC34');
            });
```

There's some way to do find out the active cell or row to put in place of the 'XXX'? I found some question on [Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32844806/maatwebsite-laravel-excel-is-it-possible-to-get-the-latest-active-row-or-cel) that someone was accessing by the variable $row, but I didn't found how to access....

Answer (score 0):

1. go to class name "LaravelExcelWorksheet" in vendor/maatwebsite/excel/src/Maatwebsite/Excel/Classes/LaravelExcelWorksheet.php
2. Try to change method modifier of getStartRow from protected to public
3. You can use it with $sheet->getStartRow(), that's show you active row

Answer (score 0):

Kaew's answer works, but to do this without modifying then LaravelExcel source, you can just use the method that getStartRow() uses internally - getHighestRow() - and add to the returned value if needed.

[Here](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel/blob/2.1/src/Maatwebsite/Excel/Classes/LaravelExcelWorksheet.php#L1148) is the Laravel Excel 2.1 source for the getStartRow() method.